# Heroku can't resolve module react-dom"

Tags: reactjs, heroku, web-deployment, package.json, react-dom

I have an app I built using create-react-app that I am struggling to deploy to Heroku. The app is built with an Express backend and proxied React server. Heroku seems unable to find react-dom, even though it is in my package JSON. Build log below:

```
> mern@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_2591a066d29a38493f0c2f48107a824f
> cd client && npm run build
> mern@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_2591a066d29a38493f0c2f48107a824f/client
> react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-dom' in 
'/tmp/build_2591a066d29a38493f0c2f48107a824f/client/src'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mern@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mern@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean 
to install?
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-22T23_39_42_140Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mern@1.0.0 build: `cd client && npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mern@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-05-22T23_39_42_170Z-debug.log
!     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi 
app.
!     Push failed
```

Client package JSON:

```
{
"name": "mern",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
"engines": {
  "npm": "5.6.0",
  "node": "8.11.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.18.0",
  "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
  "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
  "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
  "rc-checkbox": "^2.1.5",
  "react": "^16.0.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
  "react-facebook-auth": "^1.4.0",
  "react-facebook-login": "^4.0.1",
  "react-flexbox-grid": "^2.0.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
  "react-scripts": "1.0.14",
  "request": "^2.85.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

}

What I've tried:

I have run npm update in both the root and the client folder

I have installed react react-dom in the client folder

Unfortunately in all my research into this issue, everyone I've found who had this issue resolved it by doing one of either of the 2 solutions I tried. Neither worked for me.